# Jquery how to call the function in the document.ready function

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I cant control the function between the outer and inner function.
as I use a `top.out1()` in the children object. I cannot call the function run
within the `$(document).ready(function() { function inner1(){alert("alertinner")}}`
the question is:

1.How can I call the function inner() directly by the object children svg page?

2.How can I call the function inner() by the function outer1()?

3.How can I call the function outer2() by the function inner()?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function outer1(){
alert("outer1alert");
 }
$(document).ready(function() {
function inner(){
alert("inneralert");
}
});
function outer2(){
alert("outer2alert");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please re-read your question as if you were somebody else... does it make any sense whatsoever?  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Sorry! I don't understand what do you said. I want to call the function inner() as I cannot call it directly.But the question is solved by the jfriend00's helping.I appreciate his helping very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not particularly clear what you're asking.  If what you mean by "force" a function is to call it, then you can just call the function directly.

For the `outer1()` or `outer2()` functions, you can call them by executing `outer1()` or `outer2()` in any context that you want to call them from.

`inner()` is not currently a global functions, but is a local function that is callable from inside the document.ready scope in the same manner by executing `inner()`.  If you want to call `inner()` from outside that scope, then you need to define it at global scope like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.inner = function (){
        alert("inneralert");
    }
    // can call it here:
    inner();
});

// or you can call it here
inner();
```

Then, you can call it from any scope as `inner()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 i came to this question because i stuck in same situation few days ago and i just use your code and its not working in my system nor in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tauw9/ can you please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @HappySingh - The way SO works, you should ask your own question and explain your code and the problem you're having.

Comment: @jfriend00 dear i know the way of SO but i m curious in your answer that is not working in my system nor in fiddle that is the only reason to not ask question on SO. So i comment here itself. can you please help me out.

Comment: @HappySingh - You are defining `inner1()` not until the document is ready, but calling it before then so it isn't yet defined when you call it.  If you look at the javascript error console, the problem is shown pretty clearly.  I will not discuss it further here.  That is not how one uses SO.

Comment: i got your meaning thanks alot for helping me here. +1 for you. it working for me onLoad and in fiddle too.